# Blocked or failed to load JavaScript

Tags: support, browser-support

When I open the Stack Overflow site it gives me following error

> Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load.

I have up-to date Firefox V54.0.1 (32 bit). Other sites works fine on Firefox V54.0.1 (32 bit). Stack Overflow works fine on the Edge browser. Is there any problem with Stack Overflow or is the problem on my side?

[image: Request Failed]

**Browser Snap**

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't show any blocks requests...

Comment: Why i am getting this error only on firefox with only stackoverflow.. Javascript on other sites in firefox works fine..

Comment: Can't reproduce on FF.

Comment: @DragandDrop I have added screen shot of my browser. I cant use any button that trigger javaScript event. I cant add comment or post question etc.

Answer (score 1):

#### The problem is on your side.

From your comment on the question

> I have added screen shot of my browser. **I cant use any button that trigger javaScript event. I cant add comment or post question etc.**

This is because Stack Overflow fails to load jQuery, which is being prevented by your browser.

Stack Overflow requires jQuery, which is loaded from Google CDN as

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js
```

This is required for the AJAX to work.

#### Your browser is preventing it.

## Things you can try:

1. Disable all extensions.
2. Run in incognito mode

#### Another one but not applicable for you since it works fine in Edge:

3. If you are connected to a company/institution network or the domain `ajax.googleapis.com` is blocked by your ISP, you should contact them.